# I want to capture with adb commands the result of a USSD dial?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb, ussd

I want to capture with adb commands the result of a USSD dialing? connect my android cell phone with adb shell I make calls with ussd but I want to capture those results like saying the credit balance?

Comment: i doubt you can capture anything of modem from android